# Spring JPA multi module project

Tags: spring, multi-module

I am trying to create a Spring multi module project.
Module 1, handles the application startup and basic web MVC services.
Module 2, is for MultiTentanted Jpa

Module 2, runs fines fine as stand alone application, but when I include it as a dependency in module 1, I get the following error, *Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class uk.rteksoft.tenantservices.tenant.model.Role!*
I am assuming that I am missing something in a configuration bean somewhere, but haven't been able to find out what I need to do to make this work.
I have a parent pom that contains both module 1 and module 2.
Please say if I need to post any configs or other files.
Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan base package from injected module else spring will not create any bean for injected module and you will face dependency errors.

Use **scanBasePackages**  value in SpringBootApplication annotation in main application (you can scan array of packages based on your requirement)

ex:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.multimodule")
```

Here is example [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) of sample app based on multiple

ComponentScan is another way to scan multimodule packages;

```
@ComponentScan(value = "com.example.multimodule")
```

also Use below annotations for scan your entities and repositories

> @EntityScan("your entity base packages")

> @EnableJpaRepositories("your repositories base packages")

Comment: I've tried @ComponentScan and adding the scanBasePackages to the SpringBootApplication annotation with all relevant package names, but still have the same error.

Comment: @JReynolds use @EntityScan("your entity packages")
@EnableJpaRepositories("yor repositories base packages")

Comment: I have tried both of those of annotations, the repositories and EntityManagerFactories are being initialised properly, **Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'tenantdb-persistence-unit'** which is in module 2